# Serve only .js files from an Express static directory?

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, express, static

I'm looking to find out if it's possible to serve only one type of file (filtered by extension) out of an Express.js static directory.

For example, let's say I have the following Static directory:

```
Static
    FileOne.js
    FileTwo.less
    FileThree.html
    FileFour.js
```

And say I want to make *only* files with a `.js` extension available to any given request, and all other requests would get a 500 response (or something like that).

How would I go about achieving this? Does Express have a baked-in filter that I haven't been able to find, or do I need to use regular expressions?

Answer (score 6):

I use

```
app.get(/static\/.*js$/, function(r, s){
```

or

```
app.get('*', function(r, s){
  if(r.url.match(/.*js$/)) // then serve
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Doesn't appear to me that you can configure the "static" middleware in this way. In the ["serve-static" module](https://github.com/expressjs/serve-static), which is the replacement for "static" for Express 4.0 (currently in RC stage), there are some options, but not filtering.

If you want just to serve *.js files, you can create a route yourself. Create an `app.get('/static/*')` that responds with the file content and proper mime type, if the requested file is .js.

An alternative is to fork the "static" module, or better the new "serve-static", so it fits your needs.
For example, you could create a new library copying the contents of [this file](https://github.com/expressjs/serve-static/blob/master/index.js), and after the line

```
var originalUrl = url.parse(req.originalUrl);
```

You may add something like

```
if(originalUrl.slice(-3) != '.js') return next();
```

This should ignore (calling the next middleware) all requests for static files that aren't ending in ".js".
(untested, but it's inspired by the code above)

With the code above, create a new library (e.g. save it in "lib/my-static.js") and include it:

```
app.use(require('lib/my-static'))
```

Comment: Thanks @Qualcuno, I'll experiment with this and see what I can figure out.